# Is there a way to add python dependencies to conan package

Tags: python, conan, package-management

I am setting up a project using multiple libraries and packages in C/C++ and Python.

I would like to setup a binary repository for C/C++ packages and a python package index server for python packages.

I stumbled upon conan and artefactory to handle inter C/C++ libraries dependencies but I can't find a clear solution to add standard python package dependencies.

For instance, my project '**A**' (C/C++) depends on '**B**' (C/C++) that contains code generated using '**C**' tool (Python).

I would like to set a requirement for '**B**' to '**C**' as a pip requirement  for a specific distribution of my '**C**' tool package.

So far, the solutions I see are:

1. Create a conan package for my '**C'**' tool and add requirement in '**B**'
2. Handle manually the '**C**' package install in '**B**' conanfile.py

I would like to avoid to add a conan package for a python package since python has already a package management system and my packages will be available on a python index server.

I would also avoid to add code to handle python package dependencies.

Does anyone have an idea if this is possible with conan in a simple matter ?

Thank you

Alex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since a Conan recipe is also a Python script, you could run pip directly from the recipe:

```
 def system_requirements(self):
    import pip
    if hasattr(pip, "main"):
        pip.main(["install", "colorama"])
    else:
        from pip._internal import main
        main(['install', "colorama"])
```

System requirements is the best place, because is related to a required package that is not a Conan package. If you have some condition to be added based on distro, you can use distro_info too.

Take a look [here](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/methods.html#system-requirements) in the documentation, to get more information about.

Regards!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It looks like a good solution to me. 
I had been doing trying to solve python dependencies in a call to pip in configure method which was running everytime a dependent package was installing it. I didn't think of system_requirements.